# Is there any method called directly after drawRect:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, drawrect

I have two UIView subclasses, say "Class A" and "Class B". Class A, in its initializer, has the code `[self addSubview:instanceOfClassB];`. And in Class B's `drawRect:` is the line of code `[self addSubview:imageViewInstance];`. Also in Class B's `drawRect:` I assign values to that imageView instance's `animationImages`, `animationDuration`, and `animationRepeatCount` properties. However, I also call `startAnimating` on this UIImageView instance, but it always crashes the application. I then tried calling `startAnimating` on that UIImageView instance from the `drawRect:` of Class B's superview, Class A. However, it still crashes with the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

And has the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" message on the line with the code `[imageView startAnimating];`.

I suspect that it is crashing here because the `drawRect` of Class B is being called after the `drawRect` of Class A, so when I tell the image view to start animating it crashes because the image view has not been created yet.
So basically what I'm asking is **in what method can I tell the image view to start animating without a crash**?

Comment: You could add an exception breakpoint to see where exactly your code crashes: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: @weichsel - I have identified where exactly it crashes; the problem is that I cannot find an alternate way to accomplish what I describe above.

Comment: Question - Why do you add the imageViewInstance inside the drawRect? why not in the init method?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying state or calling methods unrelated to drawing from within `drawRect:` sounds like a very bad idea - You shouldn't do anything in `drawRect:` except drawing.

`drawRect:` is automatically called whenever a view or a portion of a view needs re-redrawing. The frequency and the order of redrawing operations is determined by the system and depends on several things (view hierarchy, occlusion, ...) - So you also can't rely on a specific order in which `drawRect:` gets called.

You could move the setup of your objects out of your drawing code and start the animations based on user interaction.

Comment: Hah, great minds think alike, I suppose. I prefer your wording, so I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't have answered if I had seen your's before - It was basically identical :)

Comment: @weichsel - Thanks for the answer, but my goal is for the animations to begin when the view loads, not at the prompt of the user. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You could move that into the controller. Namely into your view controller. Have a look at UIViewController's viewDidAppear: or viewDidLoad: